# How to send data to detail view from list view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, listview

I have one view where a user enters a code and a UIListView with data from parse is listed and displayed, I need to send the url to the detail view to load a page in a web view.

Comment: How are you going to your detail view? A storyboard segue or didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Also, it would be helpful if you could post the code for your:
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
prepareForSegue:
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't describe your question really well (and you should always try to put more detail on it), looks like you are trying to send a data from a table or from any another place to a new screen. So, on the xib file, you probably created a segue connecting the two viewcontrollers, so put a identifier on it, by clicking on the connection and editing the identifier. Then just call it from the didSelectRow and from wherever you want. This segue will execute the prepareForSegue method before executing the transition, so at this moment you send you url to the detail screen.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToDetailScreen" sender:nil];
    self.theUrl = @"the url";
}


 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToDetailScreen"])
     {
         NSString *url = self.theUrl;

         NewScreenViewController *newScreen = [segue destinationViewController];
         newScreen.myUrl = url;
     }

 }
```

Hope it help, and remember to improve your questions.

regards.

Comment: Hi Roberto, Sorry for the bad question structure but here is a very simple explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I am getting the list data from parse(http://parse.com/) and listing the data, I have a url column and would like each list view cell to have a hidden value of this url so that I can send the url to the detail web view.

Comment: If you have this list data in some data structure, probably an array, and you build your table based on this array, you don't need to put any hidden information on the cell. When the user select one cell the method -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath will be called, and the last parameter is the indexPath where you can get the indexPath.row (the row number). So with this information go to your array and get the url using the row number as position on the array [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].

Comment: Nice @user2802926.. accept the answer so the topic will become closed!